# Lucene.Net Understanding why TermRangeQuery with BooleanQuery results in no returned values

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

Im attempting to apply a filter to a search result, i can successfully apply 'exact match' filtering but i am trying to understand why i attempt to use a TermRangeQuery against a string field i am getting no results. e.g. given this index (i am using a BooleanQuery in the examples below as ultimately i would want to apply a set of filters)

```
    Dim stdAnalyzer As New StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30)
    Dim iWriter As New IndexWriter(directory, stdAnalyzer, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED)
    Dim doc As New Document

    doc.Add(New Field("Name", "Apple", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))        ''analyzed fields
    doc.Add(New Field("Filter_Name", "Apple", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED))        ''non analyzed fields for exact matches/filtering
    iWriter.AddDocument(doc)

    doc = New Document
    doc.Add(New Field("Name", "Apple Green", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))        ''analyzed fields
    doc.Add(New Field("Filter_Name", "Apple Green", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED))        ''non analyzed fields for exact matches/filtering
    iWriter.AddDocument(doc)

    doc = New Document
    doc.Add(New Field("Name", "Banana", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))        ''analyzed fields
    doc.Add(New Field("Filter_Name", "Banana", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED))        ''non analyzed fields for exact matches/filtering
    iWriter.AddDocument(doc)

    doc = New Document
    doc.Add(New Field("Name", "Banana Yellow", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))        ''analyzed fields
    doc.Add(New Field("Filter_Name", "Banana Yellow", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED))        ''non analyzed fields for exact matches/filtering
    iWriter.AddDocument(doc)

    doc = New Document
    doc.Add(New Field("Name", "Orange Orange", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))        ''analyzed fields
    doc.Add(New Field("Filter_Name", "Orange Orange", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED))        ''non analyzed fields for exact matches/filtering
    iWriter.AddDocument(doc)

    doc = New Document
    doc.Add(New Field("Name", "Orange", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))        ''analyzed fields
    doc.Add(New Field("Filter_Name", "Orange", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED))        ''non analyzed fields for exact matches/filtering
    iWriter.AddDocument(doc)

    doc = New Document
    doc.Add(New Field("Name", "Pear Green", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))        ''analyzed fields
    doc.Add(New Field("Filter_Name", "Pear Green", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED))        ''non analyzed fields for exact matches/filtering
    iWriter.AddDocument(doc)

    doc = New Document
    doc.Add(New Field("Name", "Pear", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED))        ''analyzed fields
    doc.Add(New Field("Filter_Name", "Pear", Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED))        ''non analyzed fields for exact matches/filtering


    iWriter.AddDocument(doc)
    iWriter.Commit()
    iWriter.Dispose()
End Sub
```

I can query for an exact match for **Apple**

```
    Using reader As IndexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, True)
        Using Searcher As New IndexSearcher(reader)
            Using analyzer As New StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30)
                Dim query As New MatchAllDocsQuery ''all docs

                Dim boolFilter As New BooleanQuery
                boolFilter.Add(New TermQuery(New Term("Filter_Name", "Apple")), Occur.MUST) ''Exact match for Apple

                Dim filter As New QueryWrapperFilter(boolFilter)
                Dim collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(reader.MaxDoc, False)
                Searcher.Search(query, filter, collector)
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

But i would like to perform greater than and less that queries,i tried to use a TermRangeQuery to find results in the **Name** field (which has been analyzed) **between** than Apple and Orange but get 0 results returned.

```
                 Using reader As IndexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, True)
        Using Searcher As New IndexSearcher(reader)
            Using analyzer As New StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30)
                Dim query As New MatchAllDocsQuery ''all docs

                Dim boolFilter As New BooleanQuery
                boolFilter.Add(New TermRangeQuery("Name", "Apple", "Orange", True, True), Occur.MUST)

                Dim Filter As New QueryWrapperFilter(boolFilter)
                Dim collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(reader.MaxDoc, False)
                Searcher.Search(query, filter, collector)

                Debug.WriteLine("Total hits Name TermRangeQuery (Apple TO Orange): " + collector.TotalHits.ToString)

                Dim topDocs = collector.TopDocs
                For Each scoreDoc In TopDocs.ScoreDocs
                    Dim doc As Document = Searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc)
                    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + doc.GetField("Name").StringValue + " Doc ID: " + scoreDoc.Doc.ToString)
                Next

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

Performing the same query against the field **Filter_Name** (which is not analyzed) **does** return results though.

```
Using reader As IndexReader = IndexReader.Open(directory, True)
        Using Searcher As New IndexSearcher(reader)
            Using analyzer As New StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30)
                Dim query As New MatchAllDocsQuery ''all docs

                Dim boolFilter As New BooleanQuery
                boolFilter.Add(New TermRangeQuery("Filter_Name", "Apple", "Orange", True, True), Occur.MUST)

                Dim Filter As New QueryWrapperFilter(boolFilter)
                Dim collector = TopScoreDocCollector.Create(reader.MaxDoc, False)
                Searcher.Search(query, filter, collector)

                Debug.WriteLine("Total hits Name TermRangeQuery (Apple TO Orange): " + collector.TotalHits.ToString)

                Dim topDocs = collector.TopDocs
                For Each scoreDoc In TopDocs.ScoreDocs
                    Dim doc As Document = Searcher.Doc(scoreDoc.Doc)
                    Debug.WriteLine("Name: " + doc.GetField("Name").StringValue + " Doc ID: " + scoreDoc.Doc.ToString)
                Next

            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

I have seen in other lucene examples that i *should* be able to perform a RangeQuery with wildcards such as [Orange TO *] but i haven't been able to produce any results have i missed something fundamental/obvious in how filtering should or dies work.

m.thanks